# Issues with linking Parse Framework for iOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have an iOS project hosted on bitbucket. It uses the Parse Framework 1.12.0.

On the machine of a colleague of mine, who's mostly working on this project no issues arise when building the project.

However, when I checkout the project and compile on XCode 7.2.1 I get the following error:

> ld: framework not found Parse

I checked the "link libraries" build phase and the framework search paths - `$(PROJECT_DIR)` set recursive - and everything seems fine.

On both machines (mine and my colleague's one) the paths don't have any space in it.

As an additional point, the same issue happens when trying to make bitrise CI build the develop branch of this project.

I know some other posts for this issue have been raised some time ago but none solved my problem.

Comment: For the sake of clarity, the problem I face is when I checkout the project on a different machine. Even though the Parse framework reference correctly points to the framework in the working copy, I get the aforementioned linking error.

Comment: Do you use CocoaPods as your dependency manager (where you get the Parse framework from)? Or how is the Parse framework integrated into your project?

Comment: No CocoaPods, just the several framework integrated in the project. All configurations in the build steps and search paths are correct